# Submit button that goes to a url based on user form input PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a dropdown search box and I want it so that when the user clicks "Check", it will go to http://example.com/check/UserInput. Is this possible to do with php/html?

```
<li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
   </a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="padding:12px;">
      <form class="form-inline">
          <input type="text" 
                 class="searchAddress2 form-control pull-left" 
                 placeholder="Address">
          <button type="submit" 
                  class="searchAddress btn btn-default pull-right">Check</button>
      </form>
   </ul>
</li>
```

For example, the user clicks the search icon, the dropdown appears, they enter "alksndlkasn" in the input form, and they click check. They are now sent to http://example.com/check/alksndlkasn.

I tried this but it isn't working.

```
 <form class="form-inline" action="https://example.com/check/text">
    <input id="text" 
           type="text" 
           class="searchAddress2 form-control pull-left" 
           placeholder="Address">
       <button type="submit" 
              class="searchAddress btn btn-default pull-right">Check</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: You have to specify an action for the `<form>`

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: See my answer @Darkstar

Comment: Isn't working @Lal. I want to go to example.com/check/userinput

Comment: I've edited your question so your code becomes visible. Please review my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you can post user input and then if it is not empty go to a link with your prefix .
simple code

```
$add = !empty( $_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : "--";
if($add !== "--" ) {
    $go = "http://example.com/check/$add";
    header("Location: $go");
}
```

Comment: Would I make a new php file with this in it and then set the action of the form to newfile.php?

Comment: you can use this page too. just use `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` and then put codes there

Comment: Figured it out. I made a new php file called check.php with the above code and then changed my form so it was <form action="check.php" method="post">

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with HTML itself.

There is an attribute named `action` for the form tag.

> The action attribute specifies where to send the form-data when a form
>   is submitted.

As an example, see this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit)

Thus, For the submit button to redirect to a page, you should specify an action for the form tag

So, Replace your form as below

```
<form class="form-inline" action="your_file.php">
     <input type="text" class="searchAddress2 form-control pull-left" placeholder="Address">
     <button type="submit" class="searchAddress btn btn-default pull-right">Check</button>
</form>
```

where `your_file.php` is the page to which it has to be redirected.

Read more about HTML form in the [docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)

Comment: Check my edit, I tried this but it isn't working. Guess I set it up wrong.

Comment: Is this an MVC architecture?

Comment: No. All I want it to do is go to example.com/check/userinput when they click submit.

Comment: what is userinput? is that a php file?

Comment: It's just whatever the user puts in the input form. <input type="text"

Comment: So when they click check it will go to example.com/check/whatever they put in the Address input box.

Comment: @Darkstar That i understood..I was asking , which page is shown when the user goes to `example.com/check/userinput`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84954/discussion-between-darkstar-and-lal).

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="padding:12px;">
                <input type="text" class="searchAddress2 form-control pull-left" placeholder="Address" id="text">
                <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="http://example.com/check/">
                <button type="submit" class="searchAddress btn btn-default pull-right" 
                onclick="window.location.replace($('#url').val()+$('#text').val())">Check</button>
           
          </ul>
</div>
```

You dont need php to do that, look at this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="padding:12px;">
                <input type="text" class="searchAddress2 form-control pull-left" placeholder="Address" id="text">
                <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="http://example.com/check/">
                <button type="submit" class="searchAddress btn btn-default pull-right" 
                onclick="window.location.replace($('#url').val()+$('#text').val())">Check</button>

          </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried to add this but when I click the input text form the dropdown dissapears

Comment: Added your updated code and it messes with my whole site layout and the dropdown doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how you want it to look, but here is a simple example of a little HTML and Javascript that lets the user select something in a form and then redirects the user to the selection. Another let's the user type in something then click a button to be redirected.

It may not do exactly what you're describing, but the javascript demonstrates how to redirect a user based on a selection in a form. You can change the form controls as you like but the concept is still the same.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function changeFunc()
{
   var tmp =  document.getElementById("myList").value;
   window.location = tmp;
}


function goFunc()
{
   var tmp1 = "http://www.example.com/check/";  
   tmp1 +=  document.getElementById("myinput").value;

   window.location =  tmp1;
}


</SCRIPT>

</HEAD>

<BODY>

<form>
<select id='myList' onchange='changeFunc()'>
  <option value="default">Default</option>
  <option value="http://cnn.com">CNN</option>
  <option value="http://www.foxnews.com">Fox News</option>  
</select>
</form>


<form>

<input type="text" id="myinput"></input>
</form>
<button onclick="goFunc()">Go!</button>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```